# Error when I am using getJson.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I wrote a javascript code to get a Json object from a url. And my code is like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('url_address', {}, function(data) {
        // do something
    });
  });
  });

});

</script>
```

And I am using Google Chrome browser. And I can get the json data correctly if I just enter the url in my browser.

But when I debug this code, I got an error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url_address'. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) which prevents browsers from making ajax requests to a resource located in a different domain.

There are two possible workaround, depends on the resource server support

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP): instead of making a ajax request the resource is loaded like a javascript function call.

```
$.getJSON('url_address?callback=?', {}, function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

Comment: Thx, Arun, the first way you said is just like what I did. I don't quite understand you.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny .it seems work now. But I don't know how to display this  json object on console or html page now. So I need time to verify it:)

Comment: @ Arun P Johny. I add a console.log(data); in the //do something part. And I used chrome console to check it. I got nothing.

Comment: @SeanZhu add a fail callback and check whether it is getting called... my guess is if the server is not supporting jsonp an error is thrown

Comment: @ Arun P Johny. The url I am using now is like that : api_url?callback=?

Comment: @SeanZhu still the server has to support jsonp, if the url is that format then the response should be `jQuery_<somenumbers>({...})`

Comment: @SeanZhu If you can share the API in quest we can have a look

Comment: @ Arun P Johny.the API is just on my localhost. I haven't put it on a server...Thanks anyway, Arun. I found it works on safari if I delete the callback.

Comment: @SeanZhu if you want to support cross domain request I suggest you add support for JSONP in your application

Comment: @ Arun P Johny.You are right. I am going to find how to add support for JSONP in my application.